# Including partials in components results in duplicate css

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, bootstrap-4, sass-loader

I'm trying to make use of the `@extend` of sass so that I don't mix markup and html together. As explained in [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-semantically-extend-bootstrap/).

In short, instead of writing

```html
<div class="alert alert-primary>This is an alert!</div>
```

You'd instead write something like

```html
<div class="banner">This is an alert!</div>
```

```css
.banner {
    @extend .alert;
    @extend .alert-primary;
}
```

Such that styling and content stay nicely separated.

**The problem**: When using this with webpack (**sass-loader**) and components (e.g. **Vue.js** or Angular), I run into a problem where including a bootstrap partial will now result in the complete compilation of the entire bootstrap file into css.
This results into a class `.btn[data-v-3614b62c]` and another `.btn[data-v-45ac961c]` etc. for every component that uses the partial `bootstrap/scss/_buttons.scss` and that for all classes defined in that partial.
Even if I don't use it.

In the long run, this will be detrimental for the application since its size will increase rapidly and I image the browser will slow down with that many css classes to parse.

**The question**(s): How do I make sure sass doesn't duplicate the entire imported partial?
Can I enable some kind of tree shaking where it only includes the classes I use?
Do I have to change my file structure so that sass understands I only need certain classes inside the partial rather than everything?

---

### Code example

This is a vue component using bootstrap

```html
<template>
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" class="input">
        <button class="button-submit">Send</button>
        <button class="button-cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";

.form {
    .button-submit {
        @extend .btn;
        @extend .btn-primary;
    }
    .button-cancel {
        @extend .btn;
        @extend .btn-danger;
    }
}
</style>
```

This will result in the entire partial `_buttons.scss` to be compiled into css instead of only `.form .button-submit` and `.form .button-cancel`.

---

### Live example

[https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-feynman-8w2kx](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-feynman-8w2kx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

To see the problem I have:

1. Right click on the example to the right and click Inspect
2. In the Elements tab, navigate to #document > html > head
3. At the bottom you'll have several `style` elements
4. Two of them will contain all the button css where only the `[data-v-######]` attribute is different and at the end are my couple of lines code.

Note that the same happens for production builds. The css is then simply bundled up in a single file, but duplicates are still around.

Answer (score 5):

If you are `@import`ing the same CSS rules into different components, then you will get the same rules duplicated across all modules. That's just how it works.

You should only be `@import`ing modules that define abstract declarations like variables, mixins, functions, etc, not actual styles.

The only way you can de-duplicate the styles globally is if you use something like [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) to extract and combine all the CSS into a single file and then run it through something like [cssnano](https://cssnano.co/optimisations/discardduplicates/) which will discard duplicate rules (although with scoped CSS, this probably won't work).

Modules are typically built independently of other modules and there isn't a simple way to know if a rule has been declared already by a previous module. In development you may be using [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) which operates on a per-module basis and injects styles into the webpage on demand; there's just no way it can work out which styles should be injected in case some particular style has already been injected by another component.

It just gets messy; keep it simple by not duplicating styles in the first place.

If you really want to use `@extend`, then make a separate `.scss` file which is the only module that `@import`s the bootstrap styles, and define all your extensions in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About importing modules that only contain abstract declarations: the problem is that I can't find any sass framework that actually exposes fully functional placeholders or mixins. If you look at the implementation of `.btn` in bootstrap, there is way too much code there instead of for example a simple `@extend %btn` so I could use `%btn`. Other sass frameworks such as Bulma and Fomantic UI seem to do the same.